# Scrollbars of ScrollView do not change when the picture is scaled in QML

Tags: qt, scrollview, qml, qtquick2

In this code, when I click `zoomIn` rectangle, the picture does zoom in, but the default scrollbars of [`ScrollView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html) do not change accordingly. They remain the same. Therefore I cannot scroll the zoomed picture.

Please point out the fault.

```
Rectangle {
    id: zoomIn
    height: 50; width: 50; color: "blue"
    Text { text: qsTr("Zoom In") }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            currentPicture.scale += 0.5
        }
    }
}

ScrollView {
    id: head
    anchors.top: buttons.bottom
    anchors.topMargin: 30
    height: 300; width: 300
    frameVisible: true

    Image {
        id: currentPicture
        height: head.height; width: head.width
        source: folderModel1.hh
        z:0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`scale`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#scale-prop) property doesn't affect the `width` and `height` of the item that it's applied to:

> A scale of less than 1.0 causes the item to be rendered at a smaller size, and a scale greater than 1.0 renders the item at a larger size.

`ScrollView` [depends](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html#details) on the `width` and `height` of the `contentItem`:

> The width and height of the child item will be used to define the size of the content area.

Since you're upscaling the image anyway, you can probably just increase the `width` and `height` instead of the `scale`.

---

> Why is the scale property there if we can bypass it without any side effects?

They have different purposes. One example that I *can* think of is animations in a grid. Take, for example, the inventory grid in a game. The items fit within the grid, and the grid expects them to all be the same width and height. If you want to animate a mouse-over effect that makes an item larger as it's hovered by the mouse, you can use the `scale` so that you don't affect the actual width and height. So, layouting could be one reason.